# Склонение словосочетания из двух существительных разного рода/числа

Tags: склонение, падежи, словосочетания

Как правильно

> "Нет дополнительной пары рублей"

или

> "Нет дополнительных пары рублей"

Какое тут действует правило? Прилагательное относится (вроде бы) к обоим существительным из словосочетания, какому отдается приоритет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: ***нет двух дополнительных рублей.***

По поводу слова "пара" - это существительное единственного числа (не числительное!), поэтому требует согласования/управления в единственном числе.

При этом, если не нарушается смысл, то лучше применять определение к самому объекту, а не к паре, хотя это и не всегда возможно, от контекста зависит.

Но тут беда другая. Использование слова "пара" для непарных по своей сути предметов нежелательно.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0+%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2

Правильно: ***нет пары дополнительных носков, нет дополнительной пары глаз***. 
С "рублями" лучше не использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: **Нет дополнительной пары рублей.**

**Пара ― существительное женского рода**, которое может использоваться при счете, но это не числительное.

Сравнить:

а) количественный оборот с числительным: **нет лишних двух рублей, нет лишних ста рублей**

б) количественный оборот с существительным: **нет лишней сотни рублей**.

**Примеры:**

Деньги ему были уже не нужны, хотя, конечно, кто откажется **от лишней пары миллионов.** [Борис Левин. Инородное тело (1965-1994)]

Разговорный (неточный) вариант: Владельцы супермаркетов отлично знают человеческую психологию и очень ловко выудят у вас **лишние пару сотен рублей.**  Правильно: **лишнюю пару сотен рублей/ лишние сто рублей.**

**ПАРА,** -ы; ж. 7. Разг. Счётное слово, обозначающее два (обычно в розничной торговле). Купить пару яблок. Мне пару пива, пожалуйста (две кружки, бутылки). // Разг. **Небольшое количество чего-л., несколько. Я отвлеку вас на пару минут. Поживи у нас пару дней. Мы с ним виделись пару раз.**

**Вывод:**

Как мы видим, в словаре приведены примеры использования слова "пара" в разговорной речи **не только в значении "пара носков"**, но и в значении "несколько".

Примеры из Нацкорпуса также **подтверждают такую возможность.**

**Можно ли использовать слово "пара" для непарных предметов?** Да в разговорной речи **это одно из самых распространенных слов**, хотя Грамота.ру (см. ссылку в предыдущем ответе) приводит в качестве примеров лишь пару ручных часов да пару трусов. Вот и вся тематика.

**А вот наша обычная разговорная речь:**

Он почувствовал себя уверенно лишь спустя **пару лет** после назначения.

Да и сам ураган хитёр. Рассеется туманом, выпадет росой на скалах, а через **пару дней** обернётся тучей грозовой.

Солнце заглядывает всего лишь на **пару часов**.

Позже они предпримут ещё **пару попыток** приостановить игру, что у них неплохо получится.

Зато сегодня на **оставшуюся пару квадратных километров** устремляется едва ли не вся богатейшая часть человечества.

**Пару раз** мы стояли на светофоре, и изумления в глазах других водителей я не заметил.

Пользоваться сервисом так просто, любой абонент осваивается **за пару минут**.

А вот выучить **пару стихотворений** и что-то изобразить я вполне мог…

По-русски он знает **пару фраз.**..

Продолжать "нежелательные" примеры можно до бесконечности.